# Proving Lagrange's identity by induction

Tags: summation, induction

I'm trying to verify Lagrange's identity ($n\geq 1, a_i,b_j\in\mathbb{R}$):

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)^2 +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2=(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2)$

by induction on $n$.

Now, the case $n=1$ is trivial, and for the inductive step I have:

$(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i b_i)^2 +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2=$

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i +a_{n+1}b_{n+1})^2+\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(\sum_{j=1}^n(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2+(a_ib_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_i))]=$

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)^2 +2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)(a_{n+1}b_{n+1})+a_{n+1}^2 b_{n+1}^2+\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n (a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2+(a_ib_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_i)^2)+\sum_{j=1}^n(a_{n+1}b_j-a_jb_{n+1})^2+(a_{n+1}b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_{n+1})^2]=$

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)^2 +2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)(a_{n+1}b_{n+1})+a_{n+1}^2 b_{n+1}^2+\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n (a_ib_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_i)^2+\sum_{j=1}^n (a_{n+1}b_j-a_jb_{n+1})^2]=$

collecting the terms $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2$ and using the inductive hypothesis I have:

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2) +2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)(a_{n+1}b_{n+1})+a_{n+1}^2 b_{n+1}^2 +\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^n (a_ib_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_i)^2+\sum_{j=1}^n (a_{n+1}b_j-a_jb_{n+1})^2]$

and that's where I stop; I can't find a way to reduce the "leftover" terms $2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)(a_{n+1}b_{n+1})+a_{n+1}^2 b_{n+1}^2 +\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^n (a_ib_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_i)^2+\sum_{j=1}^n (a_{n+1}b_j-a_jb_{n+1})^2]$ into something resembling $b_{n+1}^2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)+a_{n+1}^2(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j ^2)+a_{n+1}^2b_{n+1}^2$ (apart from this last term of course), which would allow me to conclude immediately the inductive step (since $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2)+b_{n+1}^2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)+a_{n+1}^2(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j ^2)+a_{n+1}^2b_{n+1}^2=(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i^2)(\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} b_j^2)$)

so I'd appreciate any hint about how to carry out this last step.

---

**EDIT**: I've finished the proof, I've posted my full answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lagrange's identity ($n\geq 1, a_i,b_j\in\mathbb{R}$):

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)^2 +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2=(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2)$

Proof. By induction on $n$.

The case $n=1$ is trivial, and for the inductive step I have:

$(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i b_i)^2 +\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2=$

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i +a_{n+1}b_{n+1})^2+\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}(\sum_{j=1}^n(a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2+(a_ib_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_i))]=$

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)^2 +2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)(a_{n+1}b_{n+1})+a_{n+1}^2 b_{n+1}^2+\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^n (a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2+(a_ib_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_i)^2)+\sum_{j=1}^n(a_{n+1}b_j-a_jb_{n+1})^2+(a_{n+1}b_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_{n+1})^2]=$

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)^2 +2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)(a_{n+1}b_{n+1})+a_{n+1}^2 b_{n+1}^2+\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2+\sum_{i=1}^n (a_ib_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_i)^2+\sum_{j=1}^n (a_{n+1}b_j-a_jb_{n+1})^2]=$

collecting the terms $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n (a_ib_j-a_jb_i)^2$ and using the inductive hypothesis I have:

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2) +2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)(a_{n+1}b_{n+1})+a_{n+1}^2 b_{n+1}^2 +\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i=1}^n (a_ib_{n+1}-a_{n+1}b_i)^2+\sum_{j=1}^n (a_{n+1}b_j-a_jb_{n+1})^2]=$;

expanding the squares and distributing the sums in the $[]$ parenthesis:

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2) +2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)(a_{n+1}b_{n+1})+a_{n+1}^2 b_{n+1}^2 +\frac{1}{2}[a_{n+1}^2 (\sum_{i=1}^n b_i ^2+\sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j ^2)+b_{n+1}^2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i ^2 +\sum_{j=1}^n a_j ^2)-2a_{n+1}b_{n+1}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i+\sum_{j=1}^n a_jb_j)]=$

using the index $j$ for the $b$ terms, the index $i$ for the $a$ and $ab$ terms:

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2) +2(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)(a_{n+1}b_{n+1})+a_{n+1}^2 b_{n+1}^2 +\frac{1}{2}[2a_{n+1}^2 (\sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j ^2)+2b_{n+1}^2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i ^2)-4a_{n+1}b_{n+1}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i)]=$

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2)+a_{n+1}^2 (\sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j ^2)+b_{n+1}^2(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i ^2)+a_{n+1}^2b_{n+1}^2=$

$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 +a_{n+1}^2)(\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^2 +b_{n+1}^2)=$

$(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i^2)(\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} b_j^2).\square$